# How to display diacricts marks correctly - using Webpack, Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, diacritics

I'm implementing Webpack with Typescript in project. Unfortunatelly I found problem with diactrics marks (german, polish, etc) when I've tried to display marks in console or on page. The problem is generated by webpack or ts-loader or Typescript.

The problem is not present when adding this diactric marks by simple js file. UTF-8 is present in the meta tag.

For example:

from ts file: `console.log('ü, ö, ä ą, ś, ć, ł')`

from page: [image: screenshot with problem]

from bundle.js (after translating by webpack):  `console.log('�, �, � �, �, �, �');`

The same situation is when I try to display some text on page.

Webpack.config:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './ts/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.scss'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        encoding: 'utf-8',
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: [
                            ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { regenerator: true }],
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader', 
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.css',
        }),
    ],
};
```

Tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "removeComments": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "./ts/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "random",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode=production",
    "dev:w": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fast-sass-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.88.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.18",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer.
The problem was in Visual Studio 2022. Application sets wrong encoding system as default - (Central Europe (Windows) - Codepage 1250)
To repair this, you have to change encoding on saved TS file to UTF-8